Llama-3-ELYZA-JP-8B生成AIモデルに複数のPDFを読みまさせたい
pythonでgpt4allライブラリを使ってLlama-3-ELYZA-JP-8B生成AIモデルを動かし、複数のPDFを読み込ませた後に質問すると回答するチャットツールを作成しようとしております。
しかし、以下のエラーが発生し複数のPDFの一部しか読み込ますことができません。
Llama: context full, swapping: n_past = 2048, n_keep = 1, n_discard = 1536
LLaMA ERROR: Failed to process prompt

以下にコードを示します。
import os
import PyPDF2
from gpt4all import GPT4All
from transformers import LlamaTokenizer

# GPT4Allモデルのロード
model = GPT4All("Llama-3-ELYZA-JP-8B-q4_k_m.gguf")

# トークナイザーのロード
tokenizer = LlamaTokenizer.from_pretrained("huggyllama/llama-7b")

# モデルの最大トークン数
max_token_length = 2048

# PDFファイルを一括で読み込む関数
def read_pdfs_from_directory(directory_path):
    file_contents = {}
    for filename in os.listdir(directory_path):
        file_path = os.path.join(directory_path, filename)
        if os.path.isfile(file_path) and filename.endswith(".pdf"):
            with open(file_path, "rb") as file:
                reader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(file)
                text = ""
                for page_num in range(len(reader.pages)):
                    try:
                        page = reader.pages[page_num]
                        text += page.extract_text() or ""  # Noneの可能性があるため、空文字列を追加
                    except Exception as e:
                        print(f"Error extracting text from page {page_num} of {filename}: {e}")
                file_contents[filename] = text
    return file_contents

# テキストをトークン数に基づいてチャンクに分割する関数
def split_text_into_token_chunks(text, max_length):
    tokens = tokenizer(text, return_tensors="pt", truncation=False, max_length=max_length, add_special_tokens=False)["input_ids"].squeeze().tolist()
    chunks = [tokens[i:i + max_length] for i in range(0, len(tokens), max_length)]
    return [tokenizer.decode(chunk, skip_special_tokens=True) for chunk in chunks]

# モデルでファイル内容を順次チャンクとして処理する関数
def process_files_with_model(file_contents, max_chunk_length):
    results = {}
    
    for filename, content in file_contents.items():
        print(f"Processing file: {filename}")
        
        # テキストをトークンに基づいてチャンクに分割
        text_chunks = split_text_into_token_chunks(content, max_length=max_chunk_length)
        result = ""

        # 各チャンクを順次処理（コンテキストなし、チャンク単独で処理）
        for i, chunk in enumerate(text_chunks):
            print(f"Processing chunk {i+1}/{len(text_chunks)}")
            
            # チャンクをモデルに直接送信
            result_chunk = model.generate(chunk)
            
            # 各チャンクの結果を累積
            result += result_chunk + "\n"
        
        results[filename] = result
    
    return results

# メイン処理
if __name__ == "__main__":

    directory_path = "C:/Users/15243/Desktop/python/生成AI/ファイル"  # 読み込みたいPDFファイルが格納されているディレクトリ
    
    # PDFファイルの読み込み
    file_contents = read_pdfs_from_directory(directory_path)
    
    # モデルで処理
    with model.chat_session():
        results = process_files_with_model(file_contents, max_chunk_length=max_token_length)
             
        # 連続回答
        while True:
            # ユーザーからの質問を受け付ける
            question = input("質問を入力してください（終了する場合は 'q' を入力）: ")
            
            if question.lower() == 'q':
                break

            # GPT4Allモデルに質問を送信
            prompt = f"先ほど読み込んだ文書に基づいて、以下の質問に答えてください：\n\n質問: {question}\n回答:"
            response = model.generate(prompt, max_tokens=500)
            print("回答:", response)
            print()
        print("プログラムを終了します。")

ご教示お願いいたします。

参考までに、PDF ファイルの数や合計ページ数はどの程度なのでしょうか？

PDF1ファイル、36ページ、3428単語でエラーが発生しております。
